# Missing spring http session object

Tags: java, spring, session, httpsession

I try in Spring to get the `HttpSession` like this. I know, there are better ways to do so, but this is a legacy code, so I have to handle it.

```
private static HttpSession getHttpSession() {
    ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession httpSession = requestAttributes.getRequest().getSession();
    return httpSession;
}
```

In the second line I get a NPE. The `null` is returned from `getRequest()` so `getSession()` crashes.

The method works fine in general. But there is a case where it's not. I can't image the case where Spring can't get a session from a request.

Is there a special behavior I should know about this method?

Thanks! Robert.

Comment: Calling this method before the `RequestContext` has been populated will lead to this. The population is only available (by default) if the request is already inside the `DispatcherServlet` if you want to use it outside of that register a `RequestContextListener` for early population of the `RequestContext`.

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is I have already registered it.

Comment: Also it isn't about not being able to get the session from the request there is no request at all. It will only work when the `RequestContext` is set. It is set in a `ThreadLocal` so if you spawn an new thread it will not work either because they aren't inherited. Either way you are executing some code outside the scope of a `RequestContext`. And I would put a big `@Deprecated` on there because I wouldn't suggest the use of that code at all.